# Why does a finetuned Wav2Vec2 model Inference return an empty string of transcriptions?

Tags: facebook, nlp, pytorch, tensor, transformer-model

Finetuned a Facebook wav2vec2 base model for transcriptions. Why does my model return an empty string when I try to get the transcriptions?

Comment: I have had the same issue, but can you please post a code snippet in your question? so I can help you

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @ElSheikh - Did you ever resolve your issue?

Comment: @Obie2.0 Yes I did, but I have the repo on my other laptop. In the meanwhile, will you please add a code snippet